# Windows 10 lacks partitions and WinRe options

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, recovery-partition, recovery-console

I have just installed a fresh windows 10 v1909. Having installed some apps, I activated bitlocker. Bitlocker warned me saying "something" about a recovery partition not existing and how it can be made manually if needed. When I went to disk manager there indeed was no recovery partition and all of my advanced startup options were reduced to boot options. No command prompt, no restore points... How do I remake a recovery partition that windows usually automatically creates and how do I return all of the options to WinRe/Advanced startup?
Edit: I would also like to add that the System reserved partition no longer exists and the one from which windows boots is unnamed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PCs with BIOS motherboards are often configured without a [WinRE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference) partition, instead storing WinRE on the Boot or OS partition

WinRE should always be on its own partition, but only Win ≥10 clean installs do so:

- **Windows ≥10:** `\\WinRE_partition\Recovery\WindowsRE` 
  *(Upgrade: `C:\Recovery\WindowsRE`)*
- **Windows  ≤8.1:** `C:\Recovery\WindowsRE`

**To move WinRE to its own partition:** ([`ReAgentC`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options))

1. **Open an *Admin* Terminal:** **<kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** → *Open*: `powershell` → **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>** + *OK*
2. **Backup current `winre.wim`:**

   1. Verify `%WinDir%\System32\Recovery\winre.wim` exists:

      ```powershell
      ls "C:\Windows\System32\Recovery" | FindStr /I "winre.wim" ; ls "C:\Windows\System32\Recovery" -Hidden | FindStr /I "winre.wim"
      ```
   2. If it doesn't:

      ```powershell
      Xcopy /H "C:\Recovery\WindowsRE\winre.wim" "C:\Windows\System32\Recovery"
      ```

      - **BIOS:** *May store WinRE on Boot partition: Mount Boot at `Y:` → Update WIM path 
         (Once copied over, remove `Y:` mountpoint: `DiskPart` → `Sel Vol Y` → `Remove`)*
3. **Create a 650MB WinRE partition:** **<kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** → *Open*: [**`DiskPart`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) → OK

   ```powershell
   ::# WinRE partition should have ~300MB free for future winre.wim size increases

   ::# Select OS partition: 
   sel vol c

   ::# Shrink partition by 665MB [RAW]:
   shrink desired=665 minimum=650

   ::# Create WinRE partition:

       ::# BIOS:
       cre par pri size=665 id=27

       ::# UEFI:
       cre par pri size=665 id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
       gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001

   ::# Format partition:
   format fs=ntfs quick label=WinRE

   ::# Mount partition:
   assign letter=z

   exit
   ```
4. **Disable WinRE, set custom location of `winre.wim`, and re-enable WinRE:** ([`ReAgentC`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options))

   ```powershell
   # Copy WinRE.wim:
     MkDir "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE" ; Xcopy /H "C:\Recovery\WindowsRE\WinRE.wim" "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE"

   # Disable WinRE:
     ReAgentC /Disable

   # Set Custom WinRE Path:
     ReAgentC /SetREimage /Path "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE"

   # Enable WinRE:
     ReAgentC /Enable

   # Verify:
     ReAgentC /Info

   # Remove WinRE mount point:
     DiskPart
       sel vol z
       remove
       exit
   ```

Comment: So the WinRE mountpoint is now removed, but windows defragmenter recognizes the partition as a separate drive. It also now recognizes the system reserved boot partition. Is it possible to hide them like windows does normally?

Comment: For that, I don't have an answer.  Do you have a BIOS motherboard or UEFI? BIOS: setting the WinRE partition ID to `0x27` (#3.3) identifies it as a special Windows Recovery partition, whereas w/ UEFI, the same is set via GPT ID `de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac`, w/ partition being hidden via GPT attribute `0x8000000000000001` (#3.6).  I don't have a BIOS PC to troubleshoot with `DiskPart` (verify `DiskPart` is showing the ID - `lis vol` > `sel vol <#>` > `det vol`), so you're likely going to need to refer to  Microsoft Docs, or create a second question on SuperUser for this specific issue

Comment: @Enforcer I've just checked my own PC and w/ UEFI, the WinRE partition is shown in Disk Defragmenter _(likely because it's formatted NTFS)_

Comment: Perhaps it is visible because I'vs set it up as id=27 instead of 0x27?

Comment: I have checked it out with "det vol" and it says that it isnt hidden.

Comment: So apparently id 17 is for a hidden partition and id 27 is for oem recovery. Is it possible to use multiple ids on a single partition?

Comment: `0x27` is the full hex identifier, with the full identifier only required if setting the ID after the partition is already created, and no, a partition can only have one identifier. 
 Windows previously didn't list the WinRE partition because there was no WinRE partition, and the most likely answer is that because WinRE is an NTFS partition, it's going to show as a partition under Disk Defragmenter because it's a valid partition - i.e. this is expected behavior

Comment: My boot partition is also showing as \\?\Volume{some digits}. Is it okay to change their ids to 17? or will that break something?

Comment: I'm not sure about the boot partition, but I wouldn't make changes unless you've thoroughly reviewed Microsoft Docs, especially if using BitLocker _(I haven't used a BIOS PC in 5yrs, so I'm not going to be much help here - Was WinRE stored on the boot partition, and if so, was it's mount point removed after copying the `WinRE.wim`?)_.  As to the WinRE partition, `0x27` is the [correct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-setup-diskconfiguration-disk-modifypartitions-modifypartition-typeid#biosmbr-based-systems) ID

Comment: I have set the id to 27. It is now recognized as a restore partition in disk management. It would seem that formatting it resets its id. And disk manager also no longer recognizes it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102985/discussion-between-jw0914-and-enforcer).