# "Backup & Restore (Win7)" where backup disk is not always available on schedule

Tags: windows-10, backup, scheduled-tasks

I have a Win10 machine that is supposed to do a daily system image backup to an external USB disk, using the integrated "Windows 7" backup.

The crux is, that the external harddisk is not available regularly, and even if it is, it's often not exactly on the scheduled time.

When setting it up, I was hoping the backup engine would trigger the backup as soon as the disk is back online, after the schedule was missed. However, this seems not to be the case.

Would you know any kind of settings, that would allow the backup to happen "dynamically", yet still automatically? If not, is there a way to kick off the backup via task scheduler, in some sort of construct?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You might be able to leverage some of what is explained in this answer https://superuser.com/questions/219401/starting-scheduled-task-by-detecting-connection-of-usb-device

Comment: While not addressing your question directly, WIM backups via `DISM /Capture-Image` are far more efficient, both from a size, as well as usability, efficiency, since only changed files are added to an image when a new image is appended to it, with newly appended images utilizing the same copy of unchanged files already contained within the image from the previous image(s), allowing for an image to remain small in relation to the data contained within. Please see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1544563/529800) answer, ignoring the _Configure Partitions_ section.