# Can we reduce bit by bit cloning time from source HDD to destination SSD by unallocating some memory from source HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, disk-cloning

My laptop has 465 GB of C:(windows partition) and 465 GB of D:(empty) drive. C: drive is 183 GB full, D: is empty. I want to clone entire C drive to my new 512 GB, MX500 crucial SSD such that SSD boots. Will unallocating the D drive make the bit by bit cloning process faster?

Comment: The best and most efficient way to image a partition on Windows has always been the native way Windows has always supported by capturing a WIM _(see the [**Imaging**](https://superuser.com/a/1544563/529800) section)_

Comment: Thanks @JW0914 I will look into it!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the _most_ efficient way, as AFAIK the tools do not support cloning directly to another disk – they insist on first creating a WIM image in some temporary storage before you can apply it to the target.

Comment: @user1686 W/ Windows, cloning a drive is inefficient for a variety of reasons _(requires additional steps if drives aren't the same size, requires 3rd party tools, isn't compatible with WinPE/WinRE, etc.)_, w/ 3rd party methods always fitting into one of two categories, either using Linux tools or `DISM`, which is the native way. While WIMs require a storage medium for the image, it can be saved to the drive with the imaged partitions, serving as a backup. Due to having this same conversation repeatedly w/ different users, I'm creating a question and answer that will address all of this.

Comment: @JW0914: Please do address this, as I'm fairly sure that the efficiency of file-level cloning by DISM is at best on the same level as $Bitmap-aware ntfsclone, and is very much outweighed by the need to store a huge temporary image file if it's only going to be used once. _Especially_ if you're storing it on the same disk as the source, as that way you practically get only half the normal I/O speed.

Comment: @JW0914: Although DISM is _an_ official tool, it's still a deployment and provisioning tool – it's designed around stamping the same image to many machines (after all, it powers the Windows installer), but that's not what OP is doing. And I agree that WIM file-level cloning has the advantage of not requiring to shrink the source partition (especially when it refuses to be shrunk to the needed size), and I've used it for that reason in the past, but that doesn't apply to OP's case either.

Comment: @user1686 It'll take me a few days to craft an in-depth answer - I'll reply w/ a link here Mon or Tues. `DISM` in Windows >=8, does more than just what its name implies (**D**eployment **I**mage **S**ervicing and **M**anagement, with _image_ applying to both an online installed Windows OS or offline image), and while it's mainly used by businesses via MDT or SCCM, that's largely due to Microsoft's long history of actively pushing users away from using CLI _(a significant portion of Windows users fear using CLI - contrast that with Linux or BSD)_, which is why so many 3rd party tools exist.

Comment: @user1686 [What is the most efficient, native way to image a Windows partition?](https://superuser.com/q/1581803/529800)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitions represent completely independent disk areas. If you perform a block-level clone of the C: partition, your cloning tool will *only* need to care about the 465 GB that was assigned to the C: partition, and won't even look at the rest.

(If you perform a block-level clone of the *whole disk*, it'll still spend 90% of the time cloning the C: partition, and then it'll quickly run out of space because your new SSD is smaller than the old HDD.)

What *will* make the process faster is either file-level cloning (e.g. WIM imaging) or filesystem-aware block cloning. For example, the Linux `ntfsclone` tool (which is used by CloneZilla) performs a bit-by-bit clone but it'll *skip* all blocks which have no files or other NTFS data stored on them. I would assume that commercial Windows tools do the same.

Comment: If I perform block level cloning of C:, my boot partition to my SSD, would I face problems while booting with the cloned SSD?

Comment: @helloworld1e. Any boot issues that may arise can be fixed in WinPE/WinRE by issuing the following: **BIOS**: `bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /fixboot && bootrec /rebuildbcd` || **UEFI:** `bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /rebuildbcd`

Comment: @JW0914 I finally installed  Crucial MX500 512GB today using "Acronis True Image for Crucial" cloning software, Windows booted fast and smooth after installing the SSD, no issues!!