# Multiple WinRE partitions: can I share one partition between several OS installations?

Tags: windows, partitioning, multi-boot, bitlocker, windows-re

I have two Windows 10 installations on a single GPT drive.

The current partition layout is: `EFI` `WinRE` `MSR` `...OS1...` `...OS2...`

Currently, OS1 is configured to use `WinRE` partition, as [suggested here](https://superuser.com/q/1514856). OS2 does not have any WinRE yet.

Is it possible to:

1. re-use existing (large enough) `WinRE` partition for **both** OS1 and OS2, or each installation requires separate WinRE?
2. does answer (1) change if I will have to turn BitLocker on for OS2 per employer BYOD requirements?

Also:

3. do "large" (i.e., feature) updates to both installations affect WinRE?
4. is WinRE partition required to enable BitLocker, or this is wrong?

---

UPD:

My key idea (I'm asking about how to implement it) is **to re-use 'auxiliary' partitions**, if that's possible. I would like to be able to enable BitLocker on OS2 without having to re-partition the drive (even autoshrinking `OS2` partition), so that OS2 should re-use existing `EFI`/`WinRE` partitions.

So:

1. Is it possible to re-use existing (large enough) `WinRE`/`EFI` partitions for both OS1 and OS2, with at least one OS having BitLocker turned on?
2. How should I configure OS2 to re-use one of these unencrypted partitions as a 'bitlocker-required unencrypted partition'?
3. Does re-using partitions affects somehow stability (update of WinRE by feature updates) or security?

Comment: You are aware that strictly speaking that the WinRE isn’t actually required.  I see no reason you wouldn’t be able to use the same partition.  Why are you against using two partitions?  The single partition would have to be the appropriate size, so your not gaining any additional substantial storage space, by having a single partition

Comment: @Ramhound in many cases enabling BitLocker **requires** WinRE partition. Thus I'm interested in re-using the existing one because if I could use the very same WinRE for both OS, why should I lose ~900Mb of storage space for the second duplicate one?

Comment: Are you using BitLocker now or planning on it?

Comment: @harrymc I don't use it now on both OS, only planning for OS2, as it is highly likely that it will be required by BYOD policy.

Comment: Note: BitLocker is disk-oriented, not partition-oriented, so you cannot use it this way. But it's not related to WinRE.

Comment: @simon - WinRE *can* be changed by feature updates see [Updating the on-disk Windows Recovery Environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference#updating-the-on-disk-windows-recovery-environment).  As described a new partition is created if the existing is too small or otherwise incompatible.  Bitlocker requires an unencrypted *system* partition - this is WinRE partition in BIOS systems or the EFI partition for you.

Comment: @lx07, could you please explain a bit more? It looks like the exact info I want to get... Specifically, I've launched BitLocker wizard on OS2, and it did shrink OS2 partition to create `WinRE2`, although I created both `EFI` and `WinRE` partitions are large enough (550 and 850MB). I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: I can't post an answer as I don't know whether you can share WinRE. It might not be possible as according to [here](https://rakhesh.com/windows/notes-on-windows-re/) the GUID in `bcdedit` must match the GUID in `ReAgent.xml` in the WinRE partition.  You could try checking reasons that the partition is not suitable by looking at reagentc log file.  For example try running `reagentc /enable /logpath c:\WinRE.log` on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it's possible to share one WinRE partition between multiple
installations of Windows.

To set the WinRE partition in Windows, use the command
[reagentc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options)
in an elevated Command Prompt.
For example:

```
Reagentc /setreimage /path X:\Recovery\WindowsRE
```

This requires assigning the WinRE partition a drive-letter in Disk Management,
which can be removed afterward. The above path will be translated to an
independent format, such as
`\\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk1\partition4\Recovery\WindowsRE`,
so that the drive-letter is not required.

The specified folder should contain the file `Winre.wim`, which contains
the WinRE image itself.

(I have never done it myself, but I think that this will work for you.)

Useful articles:

- [How to Use and Repair Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) on Windows 10?](http://woshub.com/restoring-windows-recovery-environment-winre-in-windows-10/#h2_4)
- [Can’t Reset Windows 10; Could not find the Recovery Environment](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/cant-reset-windows-10-could-not-find-win-re/)

Comment: I've done it before for OS1, so this works. The question is whether this won't "destroy" OS2, will have to give it a try

Comment: I wouldn't think so. WinRE should be independent from any Windows installation since it's always re-invoked from the standard `Winre.wim` in vanilla condition.

Comment: Do you also know, if "large" (i.e., feature) updates to both installations affect WinRE somehow?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it would surprise me if updating the system partition touched upon other partitions.