# Manually create recovery iso (MSI)

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, recovery

I would like to restore my MSI laptop to factory settings using the F3 menu, but the recover partition`(BIOS_RVY)` that is in the HDD that was in my laptop, is now replaced by another HDD, so I have my original HDD containing the recovery partition outside my laptop. However, I was still able to access the recovery files that are:

[image]

However, I am unable to create recovery image using MSI's Burn Recovery tool, as it says there are no hidden recovery partitions.

I want to know how I can use these files to create a recovery image/ISO so I can rest my laptop to factory default. I do not want to open my laptop and reinstall the HDD as it involves me removing a sticker on the screw, voiding the warranty.

Comment: Disk upgrades shouldn't void warranty. Usually there's a separate door just for disk and memory upgrades that's not blocked with a warranty sticker.

Comment: @gronostaj In my laptop, there is a single back panel. So I have to remove the sticker to access the components as there are no separate door. My laptop is MSI GL65 Leopard 10SEK

Comment: General info: There should be a WinRE partition on the replacement HDD; if not, it's improperly configured. These are read-only split WIM images [`.swm`] of the OS partition at its factory state, and these files can't create a bootable WinPE/WinRE image, unless `install.swm` is a WinPE image; instead, they're used within WinRE to Reset the OS and apply the images in order. These can be added to any WinRE image to operate the same way as an OEM recovery partition by editing the WinRE image with an option to run whatever script the OEM recovery image runs upon booting it to [likely `phaseB.cmd`]

Comment: _Cont'd..._ The simplest approach to resolve is to [create](https://superuser.com/a/1514869/529800) a WinRE partition on the new drive _(two if the old drive had a WinRE partition and an OEM recovery partition)_, [capture](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) a WIM of the old drive's WinRE and/or OEM recovery partition(s), then apply the captured WIM to the new partition(s). _(WinRE is easy to re-setup, however without knowing whether the OEM customized the WinRE image [`winre.wim`], the most efficient route is to capture WIMs of the old recovery partition(s) and apply it to the new ones.)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the USBrecovery from these files. Follow these steps..

1. install 7zip
2. open install.swm using zip.
3. Go to 1-windows-RE_DRIVE folder [1\Windows\RE_DRIVE\RECOVERYCD_ISO], these will be 2 folders. you will need "RECOVERYCD_ISO" folder. This folder has rest of the files you need in recovery usb.
4. copy/extract this folder on desktop
5. now copy the files you have from BIOS_RVY partition, all of it into the folder RECOVERY_DVD of that RECOVERYCD_ISO folder. [\RECOVERYCD_ISO\RECOVERY_DVD]
6. you need two extra text files, create one with name "discnum", open it and write 5 ( since you have 5 .swm files.)
7. create another text named "UFDR" and write UFDR in that text and save it.
8. That it, now use 32GB pendrive, format it with NTFS, could rename it "UFDRecovery". Even better convert USB to GPT, if you can.
9. copy all files inside RECOVERYCD_ISO to usb.
10. This is your Recovery usb...

Cheers..

[MY RECOVERY USB CREATED BY THE METHODS I EXPLAINED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plHQr.png)
[RECOVERY_DVD folder of that USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDEFZ.png)