# Is it safe to delete the recovery partition?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, recovery-partition

I am trying to grow my C: drive to use the unallocated space on Disk 0.

Is it safe to throw away the Recovery Partition (i.e. make it unallocated)? And if so, is GParted an ok tool to do that with?

And after I delete it, if I leave enough unallocated space after joining pertitions, is there a way to have it build a new recovery partition?

[image]

Comment: Was this partition there when the system was bought or was it created with a fresh install of windows?

Comment: "Safe" is in the eyes of the user. Nothing may happen, but that partition is there if you need it and there is no other way to re-create an OS on the computer.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10? If so, delete the partition. You could download an ISO to restore or reinstall Windows if something went wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to enlarge the `C:` partition, as `C:` doesn't requre >300GB if storing user data directories on a separate partition _(most efficient)_. Before deleting the WinRE partition, mount it via `diskpart` and copy the `WinRE.wim` out of it _(it's more convenient than pulling it from a Windows ISO)_. Once done, remove the mount point, delete the partition, expand `C:`, then [recreate](https://superuser.com/a/1514869/529800) the WinRE partition _(I recommend placing WinRE in front of the system partition [`C:`], else the partition order becomes an inconvenience, esp if using an SSD)_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a new partition of the same size at the end of the unallocated space.  Backup the recovery partition to that new partition.  That will be "safer".