# Moving Windows from dual-boot to a separate disk

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, migration, dualboot

I have a Windows/Linux dual-boot system on a 1TB SSD.
I want to move my Windows to a separate (256 GB) SSD and keep Linux on the 1TB SSD.
I've found several articles explaining how to move entire disks or partitions in single-boot, but very few when it comes "divorcing" a dual-boot system as I've described.
My main concerns/dilemmas are the following:

1. I only have a C: partition on Windows, but during installation Windows creates additional 1-2 partitions (for whatever reasons). My concern is that I might mess up these partitions during migration (forget to copy them , copy them in the wrong order, etc.)
2. If I move Windows to another disk, the boot manager will need to be updated to know the new location of Windows. Is this a complicated process?

As mentioned above I haven't managed to find any good article that describes my exact use-case. The few bits of information I've found were either incomplete or not really up-to-date.

Can anyone point to a good location (article, video, etc.)?
Or explain how to do this... (step-by-step)

Thanks!

Edit:
This is what my disk looks like:

[image: Disks (Linux)]

[image: Disk Management(Windows)]

Comment: Please add to your post a screenshot of Disk Management in Windows.

Comment: Is it ok if I post one from Linux Disks? It should be similar.

Comment: You could try .

Comment: @harrymc I've added a screenshot from Disks (Linux). If it's not useful, I can post a screenshot of Disk Management (from Windows), but it will take longer. Let me know.

Comment: It's not as detailed as Disk Management.

Comment: Ok, I've added a screenshot of Disk Management as well. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Please added a screenshot of the entire Disk Management, and ensure that columns are fully displayed.

Comment: I posted a new screenshot, but I'm not sure what you mean by "columns are fully displayed". If it's some setting in Disk Management, please let me know where I can find it.

Comment: @conectionist WIM the Windows OS partition _(I assume partition 4)_ and the WinRE partition _(I assume partition 1)_ by performing [Step 1](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) under _Imaging_, create the OS partition and 650MB WinRE partition _([Step 3](https://superuser.com/a/1514869/529800))_ on the 256GB SSD, then apply the WIMs _([Step 2](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800))_

Comment: It's easy enough to move the C: partition to another disk, using gparted or another product, leaving the other partitions. The problem will be to modify the boot in GRUB or whatever you use.

Comment: There is also the problem of ensuring that you don't lose everything in case of error.

Comment: Indeed, as @harrymc points out, you should have backups before even considering such operation. And yes, moving C: is easy and if you want to have Windows only then make sure you have a Windows installation media of the same version and create an empty ESP in the target drive. Then just boot the installer and follow instructions to repair boot, it should install the Windows bootloader manager in the new drive.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!